# [C++ Library]: "file or folder does not exist" when compiling

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I want to develop a small application which uses some libraries. So I downloaded them and placed the include files in a folder called `include`.

For my application, I used [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk), but my question shouldn't be limited only to this library.

This is a rough example of my folder Structure:

```
myproject
    include
        cpprest
            ...
        pplx
            ...
    test.cpp
```

And this is my Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "include/cpprest/http_client.h"
#include "include/cpprest/filestream.h"
#include "include/cpprest/json.h"

int main() {

    // code

    std::cout << "Hello World!";

    return 0;
}
```

which results in followin error code when compiling (`g++ test.cpp -o test`) with **g++** or **gcc** (on Ubuntu):

```sh
<error needed>
```

What have I done wrong? when I inspect the file mentioned in the error message, then I notice, that all includes in the library are like so `#include "cpprest/asyncrt_utils.h"`. As you can see, it refers to the file as it were in a subfolder called `cpprest`, which it is not. It is located with the other file in the same folder. I guess that results in my problem. My question now is: how do I fixe this issue?

Comment: Remove `include/` prefix from your `#include`s and then add `-I./include` to `g++` command line. If the library is not header only, you should compile it first and then link against it.

Comment: As `cpprest` uses `cmake`, it would be a good opportunity to learn `cmake`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I accidentally wrote the false name in my description. I fixed this issue.
@Evg it helped, but now I got `./include/cpprest/http_client.h:68:10: fatal error: boost/asio/ssl.hpp: file or folder not found` `#include "boost/asio/ssl.hpp"`
I hope you can help me with this issue because this should be a library-specific issue.

Comment: Now you have to add [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) into `-I`. But in the end you'll most probably get a link error. Invest some time into learning `cmake`, this investment will pay off.